# jQuery set default value of HTML <select>

Tags: jquery, html-select, default-value

My test.jsp Page is given below

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var salutation = '${reqObj.salutation}';
        if (salutation) {
            $("#ddlSalutation").val(salutation);
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="Test" action="process_test" method="post">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>Salutation :</td>
                <td><select name="ddlSalutation" id="ddlSalutation">
                        <option selected value="null">Select</option>
                        <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
                        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                        <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                        <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                        <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="left">
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Problem is that when i recieve some value from my servlet that is not exist in DropDown list values then my DropDown is showing me as blank Text.

For Example:

I recieved  `var salutation = '${reqObj.salutation}'`

```
salutation = "xyz"
```

then xyz is not present in DropDown list values then my DropDown list showing me as blank text.
I want to set Default value (`<option selected value="null">Select</option>`) on my DropDown list when i recieved value that is not present in DropDown list values.

I am using Java JSP with Eclipse Mars.

Comment: I suggest not to user the string "null" since would return true on the test `if (salutation)` Make it empty instead. That will also help with HTML5 validation if you need to make it required

Comment: @mplungjan like this "salutation === undefined || salutation == null || salutation.length <= 0"

Comment: @mplungjan can you update your answer in previous comment? I just update my Question.

Comment: You mean `var $sal = $("#ddlSalutation"); if (salutation && $sal.find('option[value="'+salutation+'"]').length > 0) $sal.val(salutation); else $sal.prop('selectedIndex', 0);` ?

Comment: @mplungjan This code will check null, undefined and empty?

Comment: Yes. But also 0 - so if you want to pass the 0 as an option, then you may want to extend the test